# cloning a multi-project repository using mercurialEclipse plugin

Tags: mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I want to clone a repository hosted on bitbucket which has several different projects within it.
When I try to do it with the mercurialEclipse plugin, it wants me to create a project in eclipse at the root of the repository, but obivously there is nothing here. I would ideally like to create different directories for the projects, then be able to treat each one as a different project in Eclipse with different perspectives, etc. 
It seems like maybe you should have seperate repositories for each project, is this the case?
Or perhaps I should just use the command line instead of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clone wizard will first clone the repository, update to the chosen branch and then on the last page search for .project files and allow you to create Eclipse projects for each. If there are no .project files checked in the last page won't be very useful. As a workaround you can manually invoke the new project wizard for each project.

I created this feature request: http://javaforge.com/issue/38534